# Navigation Component - Show different destination when BottomNavigationView's item is selected

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using Navigation component with BottomNavigationView. I am using setupWithNavController method which automatically handles menu item selection and destination redirection. It works well for simple use cases.

Now let's say I have three tabs. 1. Home 2. Favourites 3. Profile. Home tab doesn't require user login but If you want to see Favourites and Profile, user login is required. So how can I show login when Favourites or Profile is selected? Can I use OnDestinationChangedListener for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before, and I solved it this way:

First: When entering the application for the first time, i store a value under a guest name in the sharedPref

Second: in the fragment that require login check this value if the guest is true then show login screen with a button that takes the user for login fragment

Third: when the user logs in change guest value to false and when he logout again change it to true

*if you are using firebase auth u can just check for Firebase.auth.currentUser instead of doing above steps.

idk if there is security issues with that method but it works

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation , you have to use a shared `ViewModel` for all the fragments hosted in the navigation graph , and set its owner by the main activity that contain the `FragmentContainerView` and thus contain the graph itself .
So the shared `ViewModel` contain a user object for example , when user navigate to Favorite you should observe that object like this :

```
sharedViewModel.user.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (Observer<User>) user -> {
   if (user != null) {
       //there are a logged user , do nothing
   } else {
       //there are no user logged , we have to navigate to login fragment 
       navController.navigate(R.id.login_fragment);
   }
});
```

And when user redirected to login and login successfully , you can set that user object like :

```
sharedViewModel.setUser(loggedUser);
```

And finally navigate the user back to profile , which will observe that user object again but this time it will not give null so you do know that he is logged and you can do the stuff that you want then !

You can get more details for better understanding using the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login) here .

**Enjoy !**

Answer (score -1):

You should check whether user is logged-in before navigating to Profile or Favourites tabs, like this:

```
   navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when (destination.id) {
                R.id.navigation_profile -> {
                    if (!userLoggedIn) {
                        val navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
                            .setPopUpTo(
                                R.id.navigation_graph_id,
                                false
                            ).build()
                        navController.navigate(
                            R.id.navigation_login,
                            null,
                            navOptions
                        )
                        navView.visibility = GONE
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Also follow **Navigation component** official docs [Conditional navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28700068)

Comment: @tomerpacific thanks! I have updated my answer hope it may help others.